# What webmail client can I install using FTP?

Tags: email, web-server, ftp, email-server

My webhosts installed **Horde** as the webmail client, but it is quite terrible in comparison to modern software like Gmail, and its very slow.

- I installed the Free and opensource [RoundCube](http://roundcube.net/) via FTP, but probably due to its mail exchange protocol (IMAP) it doesn't always show received mails, and works unreliably.
- What else can I try?
- Have you used any FTP-installable webmail software with success?

Comment: As far as I know, _all_ webmail software uses IMAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[squirrelmail](http://squirrelmail.org/) should work ok, though you'll have to edit 2-3 cfg files
roundcube requires a database, if I am correct

Comment: I've used SquirrelMail several times before, and it should be installable without additional tools.